# Can't call methods with ether

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereumjs

I have a simple contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Reentrancy {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function depositFunds() external payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

And I'm unable to call `depositFunds()` with `truffle test`

```
let Reentrancy = artifacts.require("Reentrancy")

it('test', async () => {
    let ReentrancyDeployed = await Reentrancy.deployed()
    await ReentrancyDeployed.methods.depositFunds().send(web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"))
}
```

Looks like `ReentrancyDeployed.methods.depositFunds` is undefined, but according to [the document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-send), this is the correct way.

What was wrong?

**EDIT**

`console.log(ReentrancyDeployed.methods)` outputs the following:

```
{
  'balances(address)': [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  'depositFunds()': [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

Comment: try this var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address); give the address of your deployed contract and the api (you can probably find the api inside Reentrancy).

and is it deployed() or deploy()?

Comment: Thanks @MajdTL, I will have to supply the json interface with the Contract ABI, and I think it's not the right way to do it?

Comment: which version of web3js are you using?. Why it is not the right way!? actually it is the only way but it has been done in the background for you. Try this  -> await ReentrancyDeployed.methods.depositFunds(). sendTransaction(value: web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether")); <-. 

last option if you give up is moving from web3js to etherjs it is lighter and easier to use

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you linked the `send` method takes an `options` **object** with the [parameters](so should I report an issue for safe-react that it’s possible to create tx in such case ?) `from`,`gas`, `gasPrice`, `value`.

so for your example that would be

```js
await ReentrancyDeployed.methods.depositFunds().send({
  value: web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether")
})
```

Comment: TypeError: ReentrancyDeployed.methods.depositFunds is not a function

Comment: Truffle's contracts don't have `methods`. You should call it as `ReentrancyDeployed.depositFunds({value: ...})`.